# How to query the status of MS Teams devices via an API?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Did anyone encounter a way to query the status of MS Teams devices via an API?

Track issues like: Online/offline status, in-call, disconnected camera errors, etc?

Comment: Are you looking to get the presence status of a user in Teams? If so, please try out the [Get presence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) API.

Comment: More info on the Teams physical devices: Status, errors, hw details, etc

Comment: That is not possible with Teams. Teams cannot read the hw details and status of the physical machine.